# How can I load an entire html page with jquery including new jquery functions?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

I have two issues I'm trying to work though.

1. The first is I'm trying to set the URL to follow the AJAX crawling scheme as described by google: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174993
   when I load my two PHP pages for searching I currently just call:

mysite/search_advanced.php
mysite/mysite/search_basic.php

I'm trying to turn these URL into:

mysite/#!/search=advanced

mysite/#!/search=basic

I need the ability to call these URLs directly and have them generate the correct page.

1. My second issue is I'm unable to load my pages into a div tag because each search page has it's own set of jquery functions for onclick events.

Here is how I would like to load my search_advanced page into a div tag with an id of main:

```
$('#search_advanced').click(function(e) {

    $('#main').load("search_advanced.php");

    return false;

});
```

The header portion of my search_advanced.php page contains this:

```
<?php session_start();
include_once('functions/dbconn.php');
include_once('functions/functions.php');
include_once('check.php'); 
check_login('3');

$profile = getProfile($_SESSION['uid']);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $params = $_POST;
    if(isset($_POST['pg'])) {
    switch($_POST['pg']){
        case '10':
        $pg=10;
        break;
        case '25':
        $pg=25;
        break;
        case '50':
        $pg=50;
        break;
        default:
        $pg=10;
    }   
    }
}

function getPagination($start, $pg, $count) {
    $pager = "";
    $pages=(int)ceil($count/$pg);
    $current_page = (int)ceil(($start+1)/$pg);
    if($current_page > 1) {
        $prev_page= ($current_page-2)*$pg;
  $pager .= "<a href=\"#{$prev_page}\" class=\"pager\"><span class=\"prev\">Prev</span></a> ";
}
for ($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {
    if($current_page == $i) {
    $pager .= '<strong>'.$i.'</strong> ';
    }
    else {
        $page_start = ($i-1)*$pg;
        $pager .= "<a href=\"#{$page_start}\" class=\"pager\"><span class=\"page_no\">".$i.'</span></a> ';
    }
}
if ($current_page < $pages) {
$next_page = ($current_page)*$pg;
$pager .= "<a href=\"#{$next_page}\" class=\"pager\"><span class=\"next\">Next</span></a> ";        
}
return $pager;
}

$title="Advanced Search";
$ready_script = <<<READY_SCRIPT
$(".country").change(function(){
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ajax_region.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#state_id").html('<option value="-1">Any</option>'+html);
  }
});
});
$(".pager").click(function(){
   // my code here
});


$('#advanced_search').click(function(){
   // my code here
});
READY_SCRIPT;
```

Currently my $ready_script variable gets passed to my header.php page that gets executed from this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    <?php if (isset($ready_script)) {echo($ready_script);} ?>
}
```

I only want to call my header.php once now and load all my pages into my main div tag so I'm not continually hitting the server with uneeded calls everytime. After my onclick menu event is there a better way to initialize my jquery functions for the specific page I'm loading?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: This seems to be an instance where AJAX is not the appropriate technique.  If you need to replace all of the content on the page, including scripts, with new content, just load the new page.  Don't use AJAX for this.  What would be the point?

Comment: This is how I did it in the past but I've replaced my main menu that now retrieves profile images etc from the DB so this new header is getting called everytime with calls to my DB after every new page load.  Seems like there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your javascript from your content by putting the scripts into .js files.  After you load your content, load your scripts:

```
$('#main').load("search_advanced.php", function () {
    $.ajax({ url: "search_advanced.js", dataType: "jsonp" });
});
```

If you load the js at the same time as the content, your scripts could run prematurely.

Comment: Any ieda why this isn't getting loaded in IE?  It seems to work fine in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: I found my issue with IE. It was formatted incorrectly with two additional closing div tags.